# Display Json data in unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I want to create scoreboard with Firebase in Unity.
I know how to access data but I have problem with displaying these on screen.

I tried to add user data to list but I'm not sure if this is a good idea or if this will actually work

Here is my code:

```
public class Scoresmulti : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Zliczanie punktów i wyświetlanie wyniku
    public static int pointssum = 0;
    public Text points;
    private string user;
    public String scoresboard;
    public Array Scores;
    public List<USers> scores = new List<USers>();


    USers users = new USers();

    public static fsSerializer serializer = new fsSerializer();


    void Start()
    {
        //Posttodb();
        Debug.Log("wykonano");
        Getdata();

    }

    private void getscore()
    {
       //display text
    }
    void Update()
    {

     points.text = "Poprawne odpowiedzi:  " + pointssum;
        
    }

    private void Posttodb()
    {        user = nazwagracza.Playernick;

        if (user != null)
        {
            USers users = new USers();

            RestClient.Put("https://quizgame-inz.firebaseio.com/names/" + user + ".json", users);
        }      
    }

    private void Getdata()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        RestClient.Get("https://quizgame-inz.firebaseio.com/.json").Then(response =>
        {

            fsData userdata = fsJsonParser.Parse(response.Text);

            USers[] users = null;
            serializer.TryDeserialize(userdata, ref users);

            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                scores.Add(user);
            }

           });
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please format your post and code a little better so it's more readable?

Comment: it should be better now

Comment: Try a tutorial like  this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iAbaqGYdnyI

Just replace the highScoreEntryList with your data.